# Report code coverage result from vsts to sonar

Tags: code-coverage, azure-devops

I have generate code coverage report from vsts and trying to report the result in sonar using arguments `/d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestResults\*\*\*\*.coverage` but its throwing error

```
06:47:28.705 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor@4d437408
06:47:28.734 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestResults\Priyanka_WINDOWSVM 2016-09-21 06_47_04\In\WINDOWSVM\Priyanka_WINDOWSVM 2016-09-21 06_46_46.coverage
06:47:28.878 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@6b283550[id=213,key=MVCandWebApi,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-MVCandWebApi
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 13.942s
INFO: Final Memory: 24M/462M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while parsing the XML file: C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestResults\Priyanka_WINDOWSVM 2016-09-21 06_47_04\In\WINDOWSVM\Priyanka_WINDOWSVM 2016-09-21 06_46_46.coverage
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.XmlParserHelper.nextStartTag(XmlParserHelper.java:74)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.XmlParserHelper.checkRootTag(XmlParserHelper.java:56)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.VisualStudioCoverageXmlReportParser$Parser.checkRootTag(VisualStudioCoverageXmlReportParser.java:121)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.VisualStudioCoverageXmlReportParser$Parser.parse(VisualStudioCoverageXmlReportParser.java:56)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.VisualStudioCoverageXmlReportParser.parse(VisualStudioCoverageXmlReportParser.java:37)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.CoverageCache.readCoverageFromCacheOrParse(CoverageCache.java:38)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.CoverageAggregator.aggregate(CoverageAggregator.java:107)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.CoverageAggregator.aggregate(CoverageAggregator.java:98)
at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.CoverageReportImportSensor.analyze(CoverageReportImportSensor.java:79)
```